# Issue with HTML being returned in a $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

Hey guys I have the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {        
    $(".atf-submit").click(function () {
            atf_name = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_table");
            atf_amount = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_atf");
     runATFinsider();
    });
});
function runATFinsider(){
        var urlatfinsider = '/pcg/ATF/updateATF_window.php';
        var tagatfinsider = $("#insider_dialog");

        var promise1a = showUrlInDialogATFinsider(urlatfinsider);
        var promise2a = sendUpdateATFwindow();

        $.when(promise1a, promise2a).done(function(data1, data2) {

            tagatfinsider.html(data1[0]).dialog({
              width: '100%',
              modal: true
            }).dialog('open');
           //$('.updaterATF_outerbody').text(data2[0].atfName),
           //$('.updaterATF_outerbody').text(data2[0].atfAmount)
           //alert(data2[0].atfname);
           console.log(data2);
        });
    }
    function showUrlInDialogATFinsider(urlatfinsider)
    {
      return $.ajax({
        url: urlatfinsider
      });
    }
    function sendUpdateATFwindow()
{
  return $.ajax({
    data: {
        'atfName': atf_name.val(),
        'atfAmount': atf_amount.val()
    }
  });
}
```

Look at the top and lets say the values of `atf_name` and `atf_amount` are `'joe  and 0'`  When I do a `console.log` or `alert(data2[0].atfName)` it does not exist?  It is not defined and when I did the console.log(data2), in place of where the values should be is abunch of HTML of the table and all that the values came from.  I don't know why this is happening and it makes no sense because when I do `alert(aft_name.val())` I would get the correct value that was taken?

If you could give me a hand I would appreciate it.  Also this code runs when a dialog window is already opened and than this opens another one.  I don't think that should be a problem.

David

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type='hidden' class='user_table' value='$memusername'/>
<input type='hidden' class='user_atf' value='$memATF'/>
```

These are inside a table.

Comment: Where are you doing `alert(data[0].atfName)`?

Comment: I would do alert(data2[0].atfName in the .$when)

Comment: Could be a lot easier to debug if you can put your js and html on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @DavidBiga It's undefined because your ajax request isn't returning it.

Comment: @KevinB  How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't know, is it broken? I think it's current behavior is the expected behavior. you want your ajax request to return html, right? If not, then you need to modify your php.

Comment: No i need it return, joe and 0

Comment: then you need to modify your php, it's returning html, not joe and 0.

Comment: Like I said above in that example...I do not want HTML returned.

Comment: Why because the click event that waits will grab the name and value and I evan tested those to make sure it was getting 'joe and 0'

Comment: atf_name and atf_amount = joe and 0

Comment: @defaultNINJA I was mainly pointing out the fact that `data2` isn't `data[0]`, no where in his code is `alert(data[0]...)`

Comment: I know i missed spelled it I ment data2

Comment: @DavidBiga data1 and data2 contain what your PHP is returning. Your PHP is returning HTML, therefore data1 and data2 are going to contain HTML. If you want data1 and data2 to contain something else, you're going to have to modify the PHP.

Comment: @KevinB But that does not make sense because data1 = the url that was sent in and it opens the dialog box.....data2 SHOULd = joe and 0 but no it is HTML

Comment: No, it doesn't, It equals whatever your php tells it to equal.

Comment: I am not returning any HTML because I don't want it....the classes that the vars atf_name and amount get are input hidden boxes

Comment: Make your PHP return "Hello World!" and use `alert(data2[0])` or `alert(data[0])`, you will get "Hello World!"

Comment: @KevinB  That makes no sense?  I am not returning anything in PHP I have this same function on a different page and it works amazing.  grab value from class input - send to functions - open dialog and display THE VALUES were stored in the vars.

Comment: Why is this method missing a url option? `sendUpdateATFwindow`

Comment: What @kevin-b is trying to say is this ajax call `$.ajax({data: {'atfName': atf_name.val(),'atfAmount':atf_amount.val()}})`, sends a request to the current page and you don't have any php code to handle what is returned so the HTML for the current page is returned. You need a conditional statement on the current page to check for this request and spit out the values you want from PHP.

Comment: @Derekaug you are correct!  But I just solved it the way kevin thought I was doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this as an answer because I pointed out you don't need to ajax call to get the values of `atf_name` and `atf_amount` in the comments to your solution. My suggestion, in order to keep the changes to your code to a minimum, would be to change the `sendUpdateATFwindow()` to:

```
function sendUpdateATFwindow() { 
    return {'atfName': atf_name.val(), 'atfAmount': atf_amount.val()}; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I've done jQuery AJAX return values like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: url, 
        data: 'string'
    }).done(function(returnVar) {
        /* Do something with returnVar*/
    });
```

I honestly don't know if this will help, but it's what I've used personally.

EDIT:

Also the return in AJAX file has to be sent out.  I mainly deal with PHP files so I just do

`ECHO $myVariable;`

Comment: Ya i need to use the $.when for this one, so I have to return it.

Comment: Gotcha o'well :-) I've got nothing else to do so I'll dig around and do some research and see if I find anything.  If nothing else it helps me learn too.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I figured it out.  I actually needed to create a separate file to return the values that were sent in so I just created this:

```
$name_ATF = trim( $_POST['atfName'] );
$amount_ATF = trim( $_POST['atfAmount'] );


$returnArray = array( 'atfName' => $name_ATF, 'atfAmount' => $amount_ATF);

echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

Worked great.   Thanks guys for your hard work!

David

Comment: Why are you sending an extra request to return values you can pull straight from the page? Unless you're storing the values on the server or in a database somewhere, this request is unnecessary.

Comment: I don't know how to do it the other way @derekaug can you show me?

Comment: You should be able to change the `sendUpdateATFwindow()` function to this. `function sendUpdateATFwindow() { return {'atfName': atf_name.val(), 'atfAmount': atf_amount.val()}; }`. That way you don't send a request to spit back values you're sending to it.

Comment: @derekuag it worked...you wanna put the awnser and I will give you the point! :)